# Upload file not work with ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, oop

I tired to solve this.
my form cant upload file using ajax, but it's work without ajax.
this's my code

insertpage.php

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('document').ready(function(){

        $('#btn').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var x=$('#form1').serializeArray();
            $.post(
                $('#form1').attr('action'),
                x,
                function(){
                    $('.hasil').html('Berhasil Insert');
                    $('.hasil').fadeOut(5000);
                    $('input').val("");
                    $('textarea').val("");
                })
        })

    })

</script>

</head>
<?php 

$tanggal    = date("Y-m-d");


echo"

<body>
<form id='form1' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='simpanpage.php' method='post'>

<table>
        <tr>
            <td> Foto </td> <td> : </td> <td> <input type=file name=fotoh id=fotoh> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Judul </td> <td> : </td> <td> <input type=text name=judul id=judul maxlength='50' size='50' required placeholder='Masukan Judul'> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Deskripsi </td> <td> : </td> <td> <textarea required id=deskripsi  name='deskripsi' > </textarea> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Isi </td> <td> : </td> <td> <textarea required id=isi name='isi'> </textarea> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Label </td> <td> : </td> <td> <input type=text id=label name=label  placeholder='Masukan Label'><input type=hidden name=tgl_dibuat id=tgl_dibuat value=".$tanggal."> </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <br>
    <button id='btn'>Save</button>
<br> <div class='hasil'> </div>
</form> 

</body>
";

?>
```

koneks.php

```
<?php

class database{

private $dbHost = "localhost";
private $dbUser = "root";
private $dbPass = "";
private $dbName = "oop_blog";

    function connectMySQL(){
    mysql_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass);
    mysql_select_db($this->dbName) or die("Database tidak ada!");  
    }

    function manageinsertPage($judul, $isi, $tgl_dibuat, $deskripsi, $label){
        $lokasi     = $_FILES["fotoh"]["tmp_name"];
        $namafoto   = $_FILES["fotoh"]["name"];
        $direktori  = "gambar/$namafoto";

        if (move_uploaded_file($lokasi, $direktori))
        {
            $qry    = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pages(judul,isi,foto,tgl_dibuat,deskripsi,label) VALUES('$judul','$isi','$namafoto','$tgl_dibuat','$deskripsi','$label')");

            echo"berhasil Insert Bersama Foto";
        }

        else{
            $qry1    = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pages(judul,isi,tgl_dibuat,deskripsi,label) VALUES('$judul','$isi','$tgl_dibuat','$deskripsi','$label')");
            echo"Berhasil";
        }
    }

?>
```

simpanpage.php

```
<?php 

include "koneks.php";

$dbi = new database;

$dbi->connectMYSQL();

$dbi->manageinsertPage($_POST["judul"],$_POST["isi"],$_POST["tgl_dibuat"],$_POST["deskripsi"],$_POST["label"]);

?>
```

im just confused because, my form cant read `$_FILES['fotoh']['name'];` with ajax, that's made me fail when uploading..
the answer allways null in database.
i need help here, thank you so much

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

Comment: i guess the problem lies to var x=$('#form1').serializeArray(); checkout new Formdata()

Comment: @MehdiMaghrooni : meybe that's different my friend :)

Comment: @onegun : so what should i do with my script?

Comment: search online for the usage of formdata, one example is http://www.formget.com/ajax-image-upload-php/

Comment: @onegun okay i'll check. ty for your attention sir :)

Comment: still error.
that's not work.
@onegun

Comment: errrr... give me a moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check here, tested

```
$('document').ready(function(){

    $('#btn').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : $('#form1').attr('action'),
            type: "POST",
            data : new FormData($('#form1')[0]),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success:function(data){

            }
        });
    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a [compatible browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#Browser_compatibility), you can use the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function and [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) to do the file upload with something like this:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('#btn').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: $('#form1').attr('action'), // simpanpage.php
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'multipart/form-data', // Same as your form enctype.
      data: new FormData($('#form1')), // Your form with the file inputs.
      processData: false               // No need to process data.
    }).done(function(){
      console.log("Success: File uploaded!");
    }).fail(function(){
      console.log("Error: Failed to upload file!");
    });
  });
});
```

For more examples, please refer the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects).