# Display form output in popup overlay

Tags: php, jquery, html

TL;DR - I'd like to display the end result of a form submission in a popup overlay instead of a new tab.

I have a form that writes text on top of an image. I hit submit and it generates the image with the text embedded to it to a new page.

I am using this jQuery plugin for my popup overlay: http://dev.vast.com/jquery-popup-overlay/

To trigger the popup overlay, you have to assign a class to where you want the trigger. So I'll assign it to the form's submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="my_popup_open">
```

I create a div with an id to show where I'd like the popup overlay to be at:

```
<div id="my_popup">CONTENT GOES HERE</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".submit").click(function() {
        var imageFile = $("input#imgInp").val();
        var topLine= $("input#toptextbox").val();
        var bottomLine = $("input#bottomtextbox").val();
        var dataString = 'file-to-upload='+imageFile+'&firstname='+topLine+'&lastname='+bottomLine;
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "action.php",
          data: dataString,
          success: function() {
            // Initialize the plugin
            $('#my_popup').popup(); 
          }
        });
        return false;
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay/1.7.13/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>

<form action="">
  First name:<br>
  <input type='file' name="file-to-upload" id="imgInp">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="toptextbox"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="bottomtextbox><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="my_popup_open">
</form>
```

Recap question: So instead of opening a new page to action_page.php, how am I able to display the final result of the form within the popup overlay?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `beforeopen` callback function for that.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#my_popup').popup({
    beforeopen: function() {
      var text = 'First name: '+$('[name=firstname]').val()+'<br />';
      text += 'Last name: '+$('[name=lastname]').val();
      this.html(text);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay/1.7.13/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>
<form action="/action_page.php" method="POST">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="John"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="my_popup_open">
</form>

<div id="my_popup">asdf</div>
```

Comment: Sweetness! Now how will I be able to get the final output (the image with merged text) in the popup?

Comment: What do you mean with "final output" and "image with merged text"?? Please clarify

Comment: I have a form that writes text on top of an image that the user chooses. I hit submit and it generates said image with the text embedded to it to a new page. Instead of opening a new webpage, I would like to display the final output(image with embedded text) to the popup overlay. Let me know if I need to clarify more. Thanks!

Comment: How is that image created?

Comment: Magic and the wonderful world of PHP. The user uploads a picture of their choosing. When they hit submit, the image and text get processed in the second PHP file which uses the PHP function, [imagettftext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) to fuse the text and image together. I then place that picture in a folder using [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php).

Comment: Then you should get that image URL somehow and add it to the modal. You can change the `text=....` inside the jQuery functio

Comment: And that brings us back full circle to my initial question: How am I able to display the final result of the PHP action form within the popup overlay? The URL is created in PHP while the popup overlay is being used in a JS file.

Comment: With JS you can communicate with a PHP file. By using [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you can send info to the PHP file. There you create and save your image. Return the url of the saved image back to the JS script and insert that in your modal

Comment: Cool. I updated the code above to reflect the ajax() call. I am having trouble returning the image URL in the action.php file. First, should I set the image URL in the PHP file as a variable and return that variable? Secondly, what would I place into the success function parentheses and the .popup parentheses?

Comment: Add your `action.php` please.

Comment: Dude, there's so much code in that file. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: For a solution for you :). If you end the PHP file with echoing the URL, that can be accessed in the success function `.success( function(data) { // data is the PHP echo } );`. In this short example, `data` is the returned data from the AJAX call

Comment: As soon as you mentioned echoing the data, I started troubleshooting line by line to see what was and what wasn't working. That troubleshooting led me to find out that the uploaded images weren't processing. I found a Stack Overflow regarding passing all the form data and got it to work! :D

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @LinkinTED for the patience and ajax recommendation in outputting the end result to the webpage.

**THE SOLUTION:**

I used this [webpage's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270951/upload-file-not-work-with-ajax) solution in passing all the form data at one time.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "action.php",
            data : new FormData($('#myform')[0]),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                // Initialize the plugin
                $('#herewego').html(data);
                $('#my_popup').popup({
                    opacity: 0.1,
                    transition: 'all 0.3s',
                });
                $('#my_popup').popup("show");
            }
        });
        return false;
```

Once I was able to make sure that data was not going in NULL in the action.php file, I was able to echo the image URL and display the image in the popup overlay. Eureka!